# Can we reopen this closed/deleted question?

Tags: discussion

[How to set up gcalcli?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468907/how-to-set-up-gcalcli-on-ubuntu-14-04)

This one is quite easy, it's just an out of date package that can be updated: https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli/issues/132

I'd like to document this in this question.

Comment: Done.  Re-opened, and Undeleted.